# Remove git repository from folder

Tags: git, repository, git-submodules

I cloned into a GitHub repository named "apartments". I put the "apartments" folder into another folder named "booking" and made a new repository tied to the booking folder. The problem is that when I commit, git recognizes the "apartments" folder like a submodule. How do I remove the submodule and just commit the "apartments" folder in the "booking" repository?

I tried to remove the submodule using "git rm -r --cached apartments", but even after the command, git recognizes the "apartments" folder as a submodule. What do I do?

Comment: Remove the `.git` folder of the "apartments" folder.